# jQuery anonymous function error in CQ

Tags: jquery, aem

I'm pretty new to adobe cq5 and I'm using clientlibs to load in my jquery. The problem is whenever I load in my jQuery I get an anonymous function error specifically this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function clientlibs.js:7
(anonymous function)
```

My jQuery is pretty straightforward:

```
$(function() {
    //do some stuff
});
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error it has to be something simple I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this [.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when loading jquery through clientlibs $ isn't defined. if you want to access jquery  you can accessi t like this

```
jQuery(function() {})
```

if you want to use the $ sign inside your function you can do something like this

```
jQuery(function($) {
  var div = $('div');
}
```